# C# order a list by another list and add the ones that weren't found to the end of the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a list of values that are used to sort another list of values out, but the problem I keep running into is, if I remove 2 of the values to be sorted, the two values in the list of values that need to be sorted lost those two values because it wasn't found in the list of ordered values.

Here is my example of attempts

Attempt 1

```
universites = universites.OrderBy(d => listOrderedUniversites.IndexOf(d)).ToList();
```

the universites is a List, the orderedUniversity is a list of a model, the listOrderedUniversites is a List.

This however does pull out all of the values but it doesn't order them at all.

--- Update ---

This is what I have

```
universites = new List<SelectListItem>();
universites.Add( new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = 1,
    Test = "University 1"
});
universites.Add( new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = 2,
    Test = "University 2"
});
universites.Add( new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = 3,
    Test = "University 3"
});

ordering = new int[] {3, 1, 2};
```

So I need to order my List by the int array;

Comment: Can you provide sample lists and what the expected outcome is? Your question is currently a little unclear because I can't see how you can sort one list by another list if they are not the same length, and why the items in one list should also be in the other list.

Comment: What is `d`? is it of some class of `University`? If it is, have you overriden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of this class?

Comment: @Matthew ok so lets say orderedUniversities is {1,5,4,2,3} and universities is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} I want to order the universities to look like {1,5,4,2,3,6,7}, the reason the lists can be different in length is I am pulling them from a database and that table can increase whenever value is added, so that new value needs to be added to the list and to the ordered list or it will never show

Comment: What should happen if there's an entry in `orderedUniversities` that isn't in `universities`?

Comment: the value wouldn't be found so it would not be ordered, so that item would not be in the list

Comment: @Dmitry d is a SelectListItem, I have not overridden anything

Comment: @Canvas: it seems that not having overriden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is the root of your problems since SelectListItem hasn't done any required overrides.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem_members(v=vs.90).aspx
Equals: Determines whether the specified Object is equal to the current Object. (Inherited from Object.)

Comment: It seems that this question has now changed a lot from when I answered it. :(

Comment: Are you saying that the type of the elements of `orderedUniversities` is NOT the same as the type of the elements of `universities`? And if not, what are the types?

Comment: @Matthew I can make the orderedUniversities a List<SelectListItem> if needed

Comment: In your latest update, does the int array you mention contain indices, or does it contain values to match against the `Value` property of `SelectListItem`?

Comment: the int array would contain the values

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] The question is so unclear that I don't know if this is the right answer. I should not have tried to answer this, but I'll leave this here pending clarification from the OP.

You can do this using `Enumerable.Intersect()` and `Enumerable.Except()`.

Here's a compilable example that demonstrates it using integers (for simplicity):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> ordered   = new [] {1, 5, 4, -1, 2, 3};
            IEnumerable<int> unordered = Enumerable.Range(1, 7);

            // This prints 1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7:

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", MyOrderBy(unordered, ordered)));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> MyOrderBy<T>(IEnumerable<T> unordered, IEnumerable<T> ordered)
        {
            return ordered.Intersect(unordered).Concat(unordered.Except(ordered));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that there are no duplicates in either list.

Also note that for `Intersect()` and `Except()` to work properly, the type of the elements must have a `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` implementation appropriate for that type.

That will mean overriding them properly for your `University` type.

Comment: there will never be duplicates, however can you do this for a List<SelectListItem> and a Array of ints?

Comment: @Canvas Since I am using `IEnumerable<T>`, it will work with anything which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which is pretty much every collection type, including arrays of ints and `List<T>`. In other words, you can pass lists and arrays to the `OrderBy()` method shown above. If you want the return type to be a list, just call `ToList()` on the returned value. Likewise if you want an array, call `ToArray()`.

Comment: Note Dmitry's comments below: To be able to use `Intersect()` and `Except()` you must be able to compare the items correctly, so for a custom type you will need to override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` for that type.

Comment: @Canvas Re-reading your comments, do you mean that you want to supply an array of ints as the ordering and using it to order a collection that has a different type? That would be a very different question from your OP...

Answer (score 0):

I've modelled both right and wrong behaviour:

```
  List<String> universites = new List<String>() {
    "E", "A", "D", "C", "B"
  };

  // Desired order: A, C, D; X, Z will be ignored
  List<String> listOrderedUniversites = new List<String>() {
    "A", "C", "D", "X", "Z"
  };

  // result is "E, B, A, C, D":
  // "E" and "B" are not in listOrderedUniversites
  // and so IndexOf() returns -1 for such values 
  // that's why "E", "B" appears in the begining of the list
  // all the other items ("A", "C", "D") are sorted as expected
  String result = String.Join(", ",
    universites.OrderBy(item => listOrderedUniversites.IndexOf(item)));
```

However, if you put, say, `StringBuilder` instead of `String` everything *goes wrong*:

```
  List<StringBuilder> universites = new List<StringBuilder>() {
    new StringBuilder("E"), 
    new StringBuilder("A"), 
    new StringBuilder("D"), 
    new StringBuilder("C"), 
    new StringBuilder("B")
  };

  List<StringBuilder> listOrderedUniversites = new List<StringBuilder>() {
    new StringBuilder("A"), 
    new StringBuilder("C"), 
    new StringBuilder("D"), 
    new StringBuilder("X"), 
    new StringBuilder("Z")
  };

  // Wrong order: "E, A, D, C, B" (note "A, D, C")
  String result = String.Join(", ", universites
    .OrderBy(item => listOrderedUniversites.IndexOf(item))
    .Select(item => item.ToString()));
```

The reason is that you **have to override** `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods
to let `List.IndexOf()` work properly. Default `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` implementations take into account instances *addresses* (two objects are equal if and only if they are in fact one reference to the same instance), not their *values*.